# Xamarin, C++, Cocos2D-X and Visual Studio

Tags: ios, monodevelop, cocos2d-x, xamarin

Ok, so I currently have an iOS app that mixes iOS user interface elements and Cocos2d-x (Cocos2d C++).

I got a rough port working for Android with Java/JNI when I stumbled across Xamarin and their Visual Studio plugin. Their documentation mentions that C++ code can be used along with it, but I'm failing to find any example Xamarin projects that demonstrate this functionality.

Does Xamarin support adding C++ source to their Visual Studio projects? And, if so, does it allow for seamless compilation and debugging of that source along with the C#?

Also, are there any examples of this functionality?

Essentially I would love to use the portability of Xamarin C# User Interface stuff, along with the ton of C++ Cocos2d-x code I already have written.

Please respond with questions if I am being unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Researching this in 2014:

- The generic approach to bundling C++ code with a different language is to provide a C function call interface. This usually means your C++ code contains a factory function to return a generic pointer to your C++ object and that's passed around as a void* into the C wrappers. Just about every environment on the planet can invoke standard C functions as this is necessary to get to most low-level operating system functions.
- This Xamarin Forums [Jan 2014 article](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12174/porting-c-native-code) discusses using NDK to compile after generating wrappers with CppSharp
- Skyscanner did a two-part series on cross-platform libraries, with an [intro to the tools](http://www.skyscanner.net/blogs/developing-mobile-cross-platform-library-part-1-exploring) in Feb 2014 followed by the [C++ answer](http://www.skyscanner.net/blogs/developing-mobile-cross-platform-library-part-2-c) which has a lot of detail that may help with using C++ from Xamarin (all the crufty NDK bits).

Comment: 2016-01 After several months working (at Realm) on using C++ core components from Xamarin's C# I can confirm that the only way to invoke your C++ code remains the traditional approach of calling through a C API and flattening your object structures into parameters encoded as native C types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this exactly answers your questions, but maybe a place to start from http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html